# How to create a view of nodes of which a user is a member?

Tags: views, organic-groups

How do I create a view of Nodes that a logged in user is a member of? Is this enforced in Relationships or Contextual Filters? That is, can you explain *how* group membership is enforced via relationships and contextual filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) are providing a set a views already configured and ready to use. What you are looking for is one of these views, specifically this view: `OG User groups` of `Type: OG membership`.

You may create a clone of this view (is a good practice to keep the original view intact, mainly for reference) under `admin/structure/views` and set it  (fields, filters etc) according to your needs. You may also explore the `relationships` and `contextual filters` and see how are set. Note that the type is [OG membership](https://www.drupal.org/node/2014735). A handy thing to add to your view is the `(un) subscribe link` from/to group. This is found in fields as:`Content: Group` with formatter '`OG subscribe link`' .

Lastly, keep in mind that the OG's: `OG User groups` view is a `content pane` , not a `page`. This means that if you want to place your group's `page` under a menu you'll have to create a `view page` with a path.

[Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module also provides an [API](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.api.php/7) and set of [functions](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/7). The [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1114858) page also constitutes a great reference.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Organic Groups provises a default view for this called "OG User Groups". You can use that as a base and adapt it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Upvote. This is an excellent start to a finished solution. Would you mind explaining

Comment: If you place the default view as a block, does it give the desired result?